# Scanned Magazine Comics

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, no-computers

[image]

This drawing was sent to me by a friend a few years ago. He said it is a  kind of Mystery Case File but what to find is up to me figure them out.

Is there something to find here?

Comment: ^vote with a note: Fun mystery about a mystery, requires popular-culture knowledge. **But** looking this up on the internet would be cheating. I did. It was. Won't answer.

Comment: you should probably say what magazine it's from if you know it

Comment: The first few places I found this didn't attribute it. Didn't look further.

Comment: @humm I will say most places this comes up actually tells people what they are looking for and I dont think knowing that detracts anything from the puzzle.

Comment: @gtwebb i think the more exciting portion of this puzzle is figuring out what the picture is about. the rest is just tedious

Comment: True, @gtwebb, I enjoyed it even more after finding out, but still wanted to leave it as a mystery and just give the pop-culture caveat

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A cursory glance suggests

> There are some obvious Beatles lyrics drawn out.  Octopus's garden in the center; a guitar gently weeping in the left center.  I presume the walrus is saying "I am the walrus" to the handshake in the bottom area.  I can't tell if the meter maid is named Rita, but she is lovely.  Lol @ Norweigian Wood up top.

Comment: There's something in the pond...

Comment: Great start! According to what I found there are a total of 38 (seems most likely), 50 or 100  references.

Comment: there's the pick your own strawberry fields.  they seem to go on forever.

Comment: the store is open "24/8" - eight days a week.

Comment: The spiral slide in the top-right is a [(spoiler)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helter_Skelter_(song))

Comment: How about the Rolling Stone, BeeGees,Men at Work,the Zombies,The Who (Walrus)

Comment: bee holding a sign reading "for rent" or "to let" in British English (Let it Be)

Comment: Dont miss the "Queen"

Answer (score 6):

The other answer is the right one for correctly identifying "what is it we're looking for in this picture", but I was having fun finding them too, so...

As mentioned already in the other answer (and comments), there are

> Octopus's Garden, While My Guitar Gently Weeps, I Am The Walrus,
>  Lovely Rita (meter maid), a Norwegian Wood, a Yellow Submarine, and
>  Strawberry Fields Forever.

In addition, I can see

> A store open Eight Days A Week, Here Comes The Sun, a Long and Winding
>  Road, The Fool on the Hill, a Blackbird (singing), She Came In Through
>  The Bathroom Window, the Taxman, Doctor Robert, a Glass Onion, Baby
>  You're a Rich Man, two of the three workmen might be Fixing a Hole,
>  while the other has to Carry That Weight, Penny Lane, "Here, There and
>  Everywhere", She's Leaving Home, "Hello, Goodbye", Come Together,
>  Twist and Shout, Ticket to Ride, and Maxwell's Silver Hammer.

So that's 27.

And I really want

> the Russians on the carousel to be "Back in the USSR" somehow, but it
>  doesn't quite seem to fit...

Comment: The guy in the pond seems to be calling for "Help!". The guy with the I'm not dead sign is "only sleeping", and the guy next to him appears to be "so tired".

Comment: Have you seen the little Piggies on the van? One of the characters also seems to be a Girl. Can't tell for sure, but is that a baby driving that car? Might also be Desmond taking a trolley (in the perambulator) to the jewelry store . . .

Comment: (Girl is getting a Birthday present)

Comment: Middle, one guy says goodbye while the other says hello.